# Последовательное выполнение методов в Objective-C

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Задание звучит так:
Через две секунды после появления view запускается таймер в лейбле. После того как он доходит до определенного значения, инкремент прекращается - пауза две  секунды. Запускается таймер во втором лейбле, опять доходит до какого-то значения, инкремент прекращается, пауза. Стартует третий лейбл. 
Методы таймеров написаны, задача: произвести последовательно вызов трех методов с паузами между ними. Пробовал

```
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:x];
```

начиная с -viewDidAppear но тогда время всех пауз плюсуется и потом запускаются разом все методы. Пишу для iOS 5.x - можно использовать блоки и пр.

Буду благодарен за ответ по теме!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self youFirstMetod];
[self performSelector:@selector(yourSecondMethod) withObject:@"yourParameter or nil" afterDelay:2];
[self performSelector:@selector(yourThirdMethod) withObject:@"yourParameter or nil" afterDelay:4];
```

Если вам нужно интервал считать между запусками этих методов

Comment: Благодарю, Александр!